# Why is `TZ=Asia/Kolkata date --date="1/1/1906"` invalid?

Tags: date, timezone

When I run:

```
TZ=Asia/Kolkata date --date="1/1/1906"
```

I get:

```
date: invalid date ‘1/1/1906’
```

Here I can find a good article on that:
[Calcutta Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcutta_Time)

But the confusion also comes from the fact that 1905 was a valid date. Only 1906 wasn't. Any clue why?

Comment: obligatory tom scott video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [the time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (which gives references to other sources), on January 1, 1906, the local time¹ in Kolkata changed from an offset of 5:21:10 (“Madras time”) to an offset of 5:30 (India Standard Time), which means 8 minutes and 50 seconds were “lost” between December 31, 1905, and January 1, 1906. The latter starts at 00:08:50.

```
$ TZ=Asia/Kolkata date --date="1/1/1906 00:08:49"
date: invalid date ‘1/1/1906 00:08:49’
$ TZ=Asia/Kolkata date --date="1/1/1906 00:08:50"
Mon  1 Jan 00:08:50 IST 1906
```

Specifying the date only defaults to 00:00:00, which is invalid.

This happens whenever local time skips forward, *e.g.* when local time switches from “winter time” to “summer time” (or daylight savings time):

```
$ TZ=Europe/Paris date --date="03/29/2020 02:30"
date: invalid date ‘03/29/2020 02:30’
```

---

¹ For the time zone database’s purposes, “local time” here is defined as “railway time”, *i.e.* the time used for train timetables in the locality’s railway stations, and other railway-related events. See the India section of [the database for Asia](https://sources.debian.org/src/tzdata/2020a-1/asia/) for details.

The time zone database considers that Wikipedia’s “[Calcutta Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcutta_Time)” (5:53:20) was used until 1870, when railway stations changed to Madras time. To add to the confusion, the time zone database refers to 5:53:20 as “Howrah Mean Time” (with some doubt), and “Calcutta Time” is defined with an offset of 5:53:28, in use until June 28, 1854 (again, for railway purposes).

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is an extremely common occurrence, with many countries changing offset twice a year (so-called "Daylight Savings Time"), but often pick the date and time of changeover carefully so that the "missing" time is less likely to be encountered.

Comment: @IMSoP that’s a good point, I’ve added that to the answer, thanks!

Comment: similar: [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/995714)

Comment: @IMSoP, in this case, I suspect it was a change from solar time to zoned time.

Comment: Work with timezones in your code, they said. It will be fun, they said.